# UPS API PHP - End point URL

Tags: php, api, ups

I have downloaded a PHP SDK for the UPS API.  I have the following code and have no idea what an end point URL is.  The documentation does not provide any information on what this is.

```
  //Configuration
  $access = "0C81234564C2567";
  $userid = "leannetest";
  $passwd = "456hththd8hf";

  $accessSchemaFile = "schemas/AccessRequest.xsd";
  $requestSchemaFile = "schemas/RateRequest.xsd";
  $responseSchemaFile = "schemas/RateResponse.xsd";

  $endpointurl = 'add URL here';
  $outputFileName = "XOLTResult.xml";
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using this for a homegrown site or from a CMS? If so which one?

Comment: Where did you download this code from? UPS?

Comment: This code is downloaded from UPS, I am building my own application for UPS, its not a CMS.

Comment: I hope those aren't real credentials in this post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An API endpoint "defines the address or connection point to a Web service. It is typically represented by a simple HTTP URL string". So basically, the endpoint URL is the URL of the web service that are you attempting to interact with.

**SOURCE:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#Objects_in_WSDL_1.1_.2F_WSDL_2.0

**EDIT:** It appears from the documentation that the *Rate* webservices endpoint URL is https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Rate.

**SOURCE:**

UPS. (January 2, 2002). *Rating Package Web Services Developers Guide*. Section 1.9.3 *Server Availability Check*. Accessed in Rating API found on this page: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US

Comment: ok, that makes sense, strange that they didn't just include this in the SDK.  Does anyone know what this is for UPS?  The documentation is pretty poor!  Thanks

Comment: I did read through the documentation above but didn't realise that was the end point URL.  Many thanks.

Comment: Be aware this is testing and integration URL. See @iTechDhaval's answer for the production URL. The CIE in the URL stands for "Customer Integration Environment"

Answer (score 20):

Endpoint url explaination in the UPS document. it consists of four parts which are explained below.

For example if we are going to use "Rate" service than our urls should be as below.

- Testing and integration URL : https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate
- Production URL : https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate

---

As per the documentation if we devide the url in four parts all of them are as listed below.

**Protocol :** https
**Name of server :** wwwcie.ups.com (testing) **OR** onlinetools.ups.com (production)
**Path of service :** ups.app/xml/Rate
**name of the service** : Rate **OR** Ship **OR** QVEvents

I just replied to explain UPS endpoint url in detail so it might help

Answer (score 7):

The shipping endpoint url is:

https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Ship

In case anyone needs it, since it's not documented in their developers kit.

Comment: That url is for WebService only, what if i need to submit a pure XML request.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using **Axis 2-1.4 UPS Web Service Sample Code using Eclipse** approach. This - https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate endpoint did not work for me. So I used Yours it worked, I am a bit confused. What is the difference between these two end points?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed the documentation is poor but with a little google trick I got the list of all the endpoint URLs

Type in google search:

> site:https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/

In this way, it will show you all the endpoints.

Note: Do not use the sandbox URLs because they don't work at all :(

Anyway, here is the list:

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/TimeInTransit

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/License

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/QVEvents

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Register

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/AV

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Void

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm

https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/LabelRecovery

I hope this help